# Faillure to launch docker on OSX Yosemite

Tags: linux, macos, installation, docker, boot2docker

I'm having troubles to install Docker on Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.4): when I try with the Docker Quickstart Terminal from the Docker Toolbox I get this:

```
. '/Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh'
bash-3.2$ . '/Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh'

Creating Machine default...
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage 
STDOUT: Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 5.0.2
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

  VBoxManage [<general option>] <command>

STDERR: 
Creating VirtualBox VM...
Creating SSH key...
Creating disk image...
Creating 20000 MB hard disk image...
Converting from raw image file="stdin" to file="/Users/arbi/.docker/machine/machines/default/disk.vmdk"...
Creating dynamic image with size 20971520000 bytes (20000MB)...
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage createvm --basefolder /Users/arbi/.docker/machine/machines/default --name default --register
STDOUT: Virtual machine 'default' is created and registered.
UUID: e0f2a54b-b11a-47e2-9f3e-450f6fea78c8
Settings file: '/Users/arbi/.docker/machine/machines/default/default/default.vbox'

STDERR: 
VM CPUS: 1
VM Memory: 2048
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage modifyvm default --firmware bios --bioslogofadein off --bioslogofadeout off --bioslogodisplaytime 0 --biosbootmenu disabled --ostype Linux26_64 --cpus 1 --memory 2048 --acpi on --ioapic on --rtcuseutc on --natdnshostresolver1 off --natdnsproxy1 off --cpuhotplug off --pae on --hpet on --hwvirtex on --nestedpaging on --largepages on --vtxvpid on --accelerate3d off --boot1 dvd
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage modifyvm default --nic1 nat --nictype1 82540EM --cableconnected1 on
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
using 192.168.99.1 for dhcp address
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage list hostonlyifs
STDOUT: Name:            vboxnet0
GUID:            786f6276-656e-4074-8000-0a0027000000
DHCP:            Disabled
IPAddress:       192.168.99.1
NetworkMask:     255.255.255.0
IPV6Address:     
IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 0
HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:00
MediumType:      Ethernet
Status:          Down
VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0


STDERR: 
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage modifyvm default --nic2 hostonly --nictype2 82540EM --hostonlyadapter2 vboxnet0 --cableconnected2 on
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage storagectl default --name SATA --add sata --hostiocache on
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage storageattach default --storagectl     SATA --port 0 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium /Users/arbi/.docker/machine/machines/default/boot2docker.iso
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage storageattach default --storagectl SATA --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium /Users/arbi/.docker/machine/machines/default/disk.vmdk
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage guestproperty set default /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountPrefix /
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage guestproperty set default /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountDir /
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage sharedfolder add default --name Users --hostpath /Users --automount
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage setextradata default VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/Users 1
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
Starting VirtualBox VM...
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage showvminfo default --machinereadable
STDOUT: name="default"
groups="/"
ostype="Linux 2.6 / 3.x / 4.x (64-bit)"
UUID="e0f2a54b-b11a-47e2-9f3e-450f6fea78c8"
CfgFile="/Users/arbi/.docker/machine/machines/default/default/default.vbox"
SnapFldr="/Users/arbi/.docker/machine/machines/default/default/Snapshots"
LogFldr="/Users/arbi/.docker/machine/machines/default/default/Logs"
hardwareuuid="e0f2a54b-b11a-47e2-9f3e-450f6fea78c8"
memory=2048
. . .
SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="Users"
SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="/Users"

STDERR: 
using 192.168.99.1 for dhcp address
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage list hostonlyifs
STDOUT: Name:            vboxnet0
GUID:            786f6276-656e-4074-8000-0a0027000000
DHCP:            Disabled
IPAddress:       192.168.99.1
NetworkMask:     255.255.255.0
IPV6Address:     
IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 0
HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:00
MediumType:      Ethernet
Status:          Down
VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0


STDERR: 
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage modifyvm default --nic2 hostonly --nictype2 82540EM --hostonlyadapter2 vboxnet0 --cableconnected2 on
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage modifyvm default --natpf1 delete ssh
STDOUT: 
STDERR: VBoxManage: error: Code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057) - Invalid argument value (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RemoveRedirect(Bstr(ValueUnion.psz).raw())" at line 1766 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp

executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage modifyvm default --natpf1 ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,52532,,22
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
executing: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage startvm default --type headless
STDOUT: Waiting for VM "default" to power on...
VM "default" has been successfully started.

STDERR: 
Error creating machine: exit status 1
You will want to check the provider to make sure the machine and associated resources were properly removed.
Starting machine default...
exit status 1
Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-machine env` command.
Setting environment variables for machine default...

host is not running
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com

default is not running. Please start this with docker-machine start default
```

When I try to start the machine manually, it fails to run again:

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
Creating VirtualBox VM...
Creating SSH key...
Starting VirtualBox VM...
Error creating machine: exit status 1
You will want to check the provider to make sure the machine and associated resources were properly removed.
```

But then when I open VirtualBox, I see the `default` machine powered off, If I try to start it manually it fails and I get the following error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine default.

Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_VMM_SMAP_BUT_AC_CLEAR).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Any idea why it's failing to start the default machine?

Comment: Issue is clearly with virtual machine. Did you install virtualbox separately?

Comment: Not sure as I first installed the Toolbox, then as it didn't work I thought I've to install virtualbox so I uninstalled Docker Toolbox->Installed VirtualBox->then re-installed Docker toolbox.

Comment: Downgrading to VirtualBox 4.3 worked for me also. I think this may be related to this issue: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14412

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to downgrade to [VirtualBox 4.3](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3) to make the Docker host starts successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall VirtualBox:

```
To uninstall VirtualBox, open the disk image (dmg) file again and double-click on the uninstall icon contained therein.
```

Then re-install the Docker toolbox.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried this but I'm still seeing `host is not running` and I can't launch it manually from VirtualBox Gui